# Magnetic force vs Electric force on a charged particle

Tags: electromagnetism

Why is it that a charged particle's speed is constantly changing under the influence of an electric field, but constant when under a magnetic field?

Comment: Okay, I understand why the acceleration of charged particles under an electric field isn't constant: 

That is because the magnitude of the electric field E experienced by the charged particles is dependent on the distance between the source of the electric field and the charged particles it influences. As the distance between the two changes, so does the force experienced by the charges, and ultimately, the velocity. Am I right?

Comment: No, that isn’t correct. A particle subjected to a constant force would accelerate constantly as long as said force is applied, simply because of Newton’s law : $f = m a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the magnetic force is perpendicular to the velocity, therefore it does no work
$$q(\vec{V}×\vec{B}).\vec{V}dt =0.$$

Comment: True, but the mere fact that said magnetic force is by definition orthogonal the the speed of the body is already enough to imply that il will modify the direction of said speed (regardless of the amount if work involved).

Comment: Presenting Jensen Paull's argument slightly diferently, using the Lorentz force law and Newton's second law,$$q(\vec v \times \vec B)=m \dot {\vec v}.$$ Equating dot products with $\vec v$ of both sides, $$q(\vec v \times \vec B).\vec v =m \vec v.\dot {\vec v}.$$ So $$0=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12 m \vec v . \vec v\right)$$ So $$0= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12 m v^2\right).$$ So $v^2$ doesn't change.